# Java - Trouble Passing Variables Between Main Method and Drawing Method

Tags: java, swing, variables, drawing

I'm creating a dots and boxes program and I am trying to feed the coordinate values from the main method where the user inputs them to the paintComponent method in the JFrame class.  However I have to throw in the (Graphics g) parameter, and I don't see a way around it to feed in the values.  It's probably big cringe because I'm still starting out but any help would be great.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Dots & Boxes");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Drawing a = new Drawing();
        f.add(a);
        f.setSize(1440,990);
        f.setVisible(true);


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("You will choose two coordinates on the dot grid to place a line between.");
        System.out.println("Make sure that they are right next to each other, either vertically or horizontally (not diagonal)");
        int xOne;
        int yOne;
        int xTwo;
        int yTwo;
        boolean playerOneTurn = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 760; i++){
            System.out.println("Pick Your First X-Coordinate: ");
            xOne = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Pick Your First Y-Coordinate: ");
            yOne = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Pick Your Second X-Coordinate: ");
            xTwo = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Pick Your Second Y-Coordinate: ");
            yTwo = input.nextInt();
            playerOneTurn = !playerOneTurn;
        }
    }

}

class Drawing extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        g.drawString("0", 75, 45);
        g.drawString("1", 110, 45);
        g.drawString("2", 145, 45);
        g.drawString("3", 180, 45);
        g.drawString("4", 215, 45);
        g.drawString("5", 250, 45);
        g.drawString("6", 285, 45);
        g.drawString("7", 320, 45);
        g.drawString("8", 355, 45);
        g.drawString("9", 390, 45);
        g.drawString("10", 417, 45);
        g.drawString("11", 452, 45);
        g.drawString("12", 487, 45);
        g.drawString("13", 522, 45);
        g.drawString("14", 557, 45);
        g.drawString("15", 592, 45);
        g.drawString("16", 627, 45);
        g.drawString("17", 662, 45);
        g.drawString("18", 697, 45);
        g.drawString("19", 732, 45);


        g.drawString("0", 40, 75);
        g.drawString("1", 40, 110);
        g.drawString("2", 40, 145);
        g.drawString("3", 40, 180);
        g.drawString("4", 40, 215);
        g.drawString("5", 40, 250);
        g.drawString("6", 40, 285);
        g.drawString("7", 40, 320);
        g.drawString("8", 40, 355);
        g.drawString("9", 40, 390);
        g.drawString("10", 35, 425);
        g.drawString("11", 35, 460);
        g.drawString("12", 35, 495);
        g.drawString("13", 35, 530);
        g.drawString("14", 35, 565);
        g.drawString("15", 35, 600);
        g.drawString("16", 35, 635);
        g.drawString("17", 35, 670);
        g.drawString("18", 35, 705);
        g.drawString("19", 35, 740);

        int dotx1 = 80;
        int doty1 = 70;
        ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));

        for (int h = 0; h <= 19; h++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
                g.drawLine(dotx1, doty1, dotx1, doty1);
                dotx1 = dotx1 + 35;
            }
            dotx1 = 80;
            doty1 = doty1 + 35;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling any method in Drawing, what is your point?

Comment: Isn't paintComponent a swing method?  I'm having trouble bringing xOne, yOne, xTwo, and yTwo to the paintComponent method to draw the lines.

Comment: yes, paintComponent is a method, but you are not calling it in the code you've written.

Comment: I don't really need to call it though, that's what lines 6-11 are doing.

Comment: You shouldn't call the method `paintComponent`. You simply need to provide a list of your boxes. Your main loop puts into this list coordinates of boxes, and the method `paintComponent` gets the boxes from the list and draws them.

Comment: How can i get the `paintComponent` method to grab them from the list in the main method?  The main part that I'm struggling with is just passing everything between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call paintComponent by yourself. The method is called when Java is drawing the window.
The reason is that the user shouldn't care about re-drawing, most of the time. Java will decide when to redraw, for example on window minimize/maximize or resizing or when an element is clicked.

To draw animated shapes you must ask Java to redraw your window. You can add `f.revalidate()` to force components to redraw. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()).

**Be really careful** when using this. Never call this inside a loop without waiting between frames, because your CPU will go crazy if not !
If you want animated shapes, call `revalidate()` at fixed rate, for example 60fps.

In your case, you could simple put your Scanner inside the loop, ask the user for input, process it and then redraw the window.

Also, revalidate() is not blocking, it will just tell Java that the components tree has changed and must be redraw. But it will do it when he will have the time to do it.

Edit : As we are discussing in commentary, to feed your Drawing with the data to draw you must give him the informations.
First, create your graphical elements, let start with points :

```
class Point {
    public float x, y;

    Point(float x, float y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }
}
```

In your Drawing (who is in fact your Scene, let rename it), add setters and List

```
class Scene {
    private List<Point> mPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();

    public addPoint(Point p) {
        mPoints.add(p);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ....
        for (Point p : mPoints) {
            // draw your points here
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

There several way to improve this simple example. First, you could add a paint(Graphics g) method on Point class.
When you will add another kind of component, you should create a base class Item and extend it in your graphical items (Point, Box...) and put the paint method in this new base class.
It's the way to don't have one list for each kind of element, and then you can just iterate over items and call paint without worrying about the kind behind it (Point, Box...)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm getting stuck on processing the input after the user puts it in from the for loop.  I need to get it over to the `paintComponent` method but I don't know how.

Comment: Just pass your elements to your class "Drawing". It can be at creation or with setters.
You can see your Drawing as a SceneManager or something like this.
I suggest you to create a "Box" class and/or "Point" class who will handle both kind of object you want to draw. Then, when the user have entered some interesting information create for ex. Point(50, 50) and add it to your scene (drawing.add(new Point(50, 50)). And in the painComponent just iterate over your list of items